# Centering logo in header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I know I must be missing something stupid but I can't figure out why my logo will not center on our mobile site. Please check out this site at under 770px screen width: http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev

CSS:

```
.main-header .logo-and-menu-container .logo-column {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 770px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block;
    min-height: 120px;
}
.header-logo.logo-image img{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width:304px;
}
.main-header .logo-and-menu-container .logo-column::after{ 
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both !important;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="logo-column">
            <style>.logo-image { width: 304px; }</style><a class="header-logo logo-image" href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev">
<img width="304" height="108" alt="logo" src="//www.estiponagroup.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/eg-logo-300.png">
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of getting this logo to center?

Comment: It is working fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/px46uvz8/

Comment: It's not centered in chrome.

Comment: I am working in FF and it isn't working either. Maybe a setting in a parent div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to that media query

```
@media (max-width: 770px){
      .logo-image {
        max-width: 384px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how css works.

All your elements inherate some property from their parents.

So in you case the website your are showing the logo-column class is limiting the size of the div, so the logo can't be in the center because he is limited widrth 80px and with a margin-right.

So i tested in my browser and changed to this.

Change the inline [line 86] class .main-header .logo-and-menu-container .logo-column to this

```
width:100%
max-width:100%;
```

I also added a margin-left and right to auto and set to display block, doing this (raising the width size and setting the < a > element to the code below allow your logo to be right in the middle.

```
 <a style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; display: block;" href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev" class="header-logo logo-image">
```

Ps.: You should change the "hard code" in the css to the css file.

Check the result : http://snag.gy/pfsk1.jpg

Comment: inline style is not the way to go, user wants the change only on mobile viewing.

Comment: I agree with you, he needs to change the code for the right file, i was just saying that with the actual code of him it will stuck if he tries to center the div that it's limited by their parent.

Comment: In the future try to answer the question as thorough as possible, I see you put a lot of time in your answer so you are on the right track, look at my answer, it is short sweet and to the point. it answers all the issues, I am not trying to beet you up, if I had any votes left today, I would still upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete rule:

```
media="all" .header-logo.logo-image
display: block;
```

and add:

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
```

on the image (for right media size).

Answer (score 0):

Give a `margin: 0 auto;` on the  tag around the logo in the media query

```
.main-header .logo-and-menu-container .logo-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a complete and perfect reference for centering every things.
[centering elements with css](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)